# JQuery Hover over child element to change CSS of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, navigation

I have a drop down box navigation menu on my website here: users.aber.ac.uk/mta2/cs15020

There were minor problems with my drop downs since css can't affect parent elements when hovering children.

This is my navigaton menu including JQuery

At the moment it is affecting all the .navlists and makes them stick.

```
<h1 id = "title">  Max Atkins </h1>
            <ul id="menu"> <!-- Drop down navigation menu --> 
                <li class = "navlists">
                    <a href ="../"> Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class = "navlists"> <!-- Main buttons -->
                    <a> Web Assignment </a>
                    <ul class = "sub-menu"> <!-- Drop downs --> 
                        <li class = "sublists">
                            <a href = "./cv.shtml"> CV </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class = "lastitem"> <!-- Specific styling for this link --> 
                            <a href = "./writeup.shtml"> Write-Up </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class = "navlists"> <!-- Main buttons -->
                    <a> Richard's Assignment </a> 
                    <ul class = "sub-menu"> <!-- Drop downs --> 
                        <li class = "sublists">
                            <a href = "wordpress"> WordPress </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class = "lastitem"> <!-- Specific styling for this link --> 
                            <a href = "webshop/catalog"> WebShop </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>

            $(document).ready(function () 
            {
                $(".navlists > a").hover(function() 
                {
                    $(this).find(".navlists > a").css("border-bottom-left-radius", "0");
                    $(this).find(".navlists > a").css("border-bottom-right-radius", "0");

                    $(".sublists > a, .lastitem > a").hover(function () 
                    {
                        $(".navlists > a").css("border-bottom-left-radius", "0");
                        $(".navlists > a").css("border-bottom-right-radius", "0");
                    });
                }); 

                $(".sublists > a, .lastitem > a").mouseleave(function () 
                {
                    $(".navlists > a").css("border-bottom-left-radius", "15px");
                    $(".navlists > a").css("border-bottom-right-radius", "15px");
                });
            });


            </script>
```

Comment: what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Your code is looking for `.navlists > a` within `.navlists > a` so it won't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this purely with css

you just need to use the `:hover` selector on the top level `li` and to make selectors easier add a class to menu items that have a submenu like `class="hasSub"`

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vxuph/1/

Comment: thanks a bunch :D now my lecturer won't think im an idiot for using JQuery on something so simple

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly. Try to use parent():

```
$(this).find(".navlists > a").parent().css('...','...');
```